# Extract all Capitalized words from document using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, extract, capitalization

Using PowerShell extract all Capitalized words from a Document. Everything works until the last line of code as far as I can tell. Something wrong with my RegEx or is my approach all wrong?

```
#Extract content of Microsoft Word Document to text
$word = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $True 
$doc = $word.Documents.Open("D:\Deleteme\test.docx") 
$sel = $word.Selection
$paras = $doc.Paragraphs

$path = "D:\deleteme\words.txt"

foreach ($para in $paras) 
{ 
    $para.Range.Text | Out-File -FilePath $path -Append
}

#Find all capitalized words :( Everything works except this. I want to extract all Capitalized words
$capwords = Get-Content $path | Select-string -pattern "/\b[A-Z]+\b/g"
```

Comment: PowerShell is generally case-_insensitive_. Therefore, case-_sensitive_ operations require _opt-in_. In the case of [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) this means adding the `-CaseSensitive` switch.

Comment: @mklement0 -CaseSensitive had no affect. I was also under the impression that RegEx patterns indicate case so I do not need to that switch

Comment: No, unless you explicitly request case-sensitivity, `[A-Z]` is treated as `[A-Za-z]`. Try `'f' | Select-String -Quiet '[A-Z]'` (`$true`) vs. `'f' | Select-String -CaseSensitive  -Quiet '[A-Z]'` (no output). Note that the accepted answer uses `-cmatch`, the case-sensitive variant of the `-match` operator.

Comment: I hadn't looked closely enough originally: `-CaseSensitive` was only part of the puzzle; there's also a problem with your regex and with how you access the matching results - please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- PowerShell uses *strings* to store regexes and has *no* syntax for regex *literals* such as `/.../` - nor for post-positional matching *options* such as `g`.
- PowerShell is case-*insensitive* by default and requires *opt-in* for case-sensitivity (`-CaseSensitive` in the case of [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)).

  - Without that, `[A-Z]` is effectively the same as `[A-Za-z]` and therefore matches both upper- and lowercase (English) letters.
- The equivalent of the `g` option is `Select-String`'s `-AllMatches` switch, which looks for *all* matches on each input line (by default, it only looks for the *first*.
- What `Select-String` outputs aren't *strings*, i.e. not the matching lines directly, but *wrapper objects* of type [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) with metadata about each match.

  - Instances of that type have a `.Matches` property that contains array of [`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match) instances, whose `.Value` property contains the text of each match (whereas the `.Line` property contains the matching line in full).

To put it all together:

```sh
$capwords = Get-Content -Raw $path |
  Select-String -CaseSensitive -AllMatches -Pattern '\b[A-Z]+\b' |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
```

Note the use of `-Raw` with [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content), which greatly speeds up processing, because the entire file content is read as a *single, multi-line string* - essentially, `Select-String` then sees the entire content as a single "line". This optimization is possible, because you're not interested in line-by-line processing and only care about what the regex captured, across all lines.

As an aside:

`$_.Matches.Value` takes advantage of PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375), which you can similarly leverage to avoid having to loop over the paragraphs in `$paras` explicitly:

```sh
# Use member-access enumeration on collection $paras to get the .Range
# property values of all collection elements and access their .Text
# property value.
$paras.Range.Text | Out-File -FilePath $path
```

---

**.NET API alternative:**

The [`[regex]::Matches()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches) .NET method allows for a more concise - and better-performing - alternative:

```sh
$capwords = [regex]::Matches((Get-Content -Raw $path), '\b[A-Z]+\b').Value
```

Note that, in contrast with PowerShell, the .NET regex APIs are case-*sensitive* by default, so no opt-in is required.

`.Value` again utilizes member-access enumeration in order to extract the matching text from all returned match-information objects.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your script and was able to get all the upper-case words in my test doc.

```
$word = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $True 
$doc = $word.Documents.Open("D:\WordTest\test.docx") 
$sel = $word.Selection
$paras = $doc.Paragraphs

$path = "D:\WordTest\words.txt"

foreach ($para in $paras) 
{ 
    $para.Range.Text | Out-File -FilePath $path -Append
}

# Get all words in the content
$AllWords = (Get-Content $path)

# Split all words into an array
$WordArray = ($AllWords).split(' ')

# Create array for capitalized words to capture them during ForEach loop
$CapWords = @()

# ForEach loop for each word in the array
foreach($SingleWord in $WordArray){

    # Perform a check to see if the word is fully capitalized
    $Check = $SingleWord -cmatch '\b[A-Z]+\b'
    
    # If check is true, remove special characters and put it into the $CapWords array
    if($Check -eq $True){
        $SingleWord = $SingleWord -replace '[\W]', ''
        $CapWords += $SingleWord
    }
}
```

I had it come out as an array of capitalized words, but you could always join it back if you wanted it to be a string:

```
$CapString = $CapWords -join " "
```